# OpenGL - mask with multiple textures

Tags: c++, opengl, mask, blending

I have implemented masking in OpenGL according to the following concept:

- The mask is composed of black and white colors.
- A foreground texture should only be visible in the white parts of the mask.
- A background texture should only be visible in the black parts of the mask.

I can make the white part or the black part work as supposed by using glBlendFunc(), but not the two at the same time, because the foreground layer not only blends onto the mask, but also onto the background layer.

Is there anyone who knows how to accomplish this in the best way? I have been searching the net and read something about fragment shaders. Is this the way to go?

Comment: I know there's a way of doing this, I'm pretty sure it's a simple 'mask' function, but it's been *ages* since I last used OpenGL.  Have you seen: http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=20

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Yes, my implementation is based on that tutorial and works for one mask with one texture, but when I use two textures for one mask as described above, the result is not what I expected: the foreground image colors also blend onto the background layer instead of the mask alone. Should I post a screenshot to illustrate my problem?

Comment: It's a very basic (simple) task for a fragment shader. Though, I can't point you to a proper Fixed-Function solution.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This should work:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
// Use a simple blendfunc for drawing the background
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
// Draw entire background without masking
drawQuad(backgroundTexture);
// Next, we want a blendfunc that doesn't change the color of any pixels,
// but rather replaces the framebuffer alpha values with values based
// on the whiteness of the mask. In other words, if a pixel is white in the mask,
// then the corresponding framebuffer pixel's alpha will be set to 1.
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
// Now "draw" the mask (again, this doesn't produce a visible result, it just
// changes the alpha values in the framebuffer)
drawQuad(maskTexture);
// Finally, we want a blendfunc that makes the foreground visible only in
// areas with high alpha.
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
drawQuad(foregroundTexture);
```

This is fairly tricky, so tell me if anything is unclear.

Don't forget to [request an alpha buffer](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm#blen0050) when creating the GL context. Otherwise it's possible to get a context without an alpha buffer.

**Edit:** Here, I made an illustration.
[image: illustration]

**Edit:** Since writing this answer, I've learned that there are better ways to do this:

- If you're limited to OpenGL's fixed-function pipeline, use texture environments
- If you can use shaders, use a fragment shader.

The way described in this answer works and is not particularly worse in performance than these 2 better options, but is less elegant and less flexible.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! I could not wish for a better answer! In my implementation I replaced glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ZERO) with glBlendFuncSeparate and now it works. So my mistake was that the glBlendFunc immediately replaces colors.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without calling glBlendFuncSeparate? It causes segfaults with my graphics card when I put that line in.

Comment: It does not work for me either :( Only the foreground is shown

Comment: How would you go about making a fragment shader? How would it know about the masking layer?

Comment: is this possible to achieve with stencils?

Comment: @riggaroo: Yes, but the result will lose the antialiasing.

Comment: @PostSelf: You can provide several textures as inputs to a shader (as "uniforms")

Comment: @Skyler: You probably need to use an extension-loading mechanism such as GLEW.

Answer (score 0):

Stefan Monov's is great answer! But for those who still have issues to get his answer working:

1. you need to check GLES20.glGetIntegerv(GLES20.GL_ALPHA_BITS, ib) - you need non zero result.
2. if you got 0 - goto EGLConfig and ensure that you pass alpha bits

   ```
   EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
   EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
   EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
   EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8, <- i havn't this and spent a much of time
   EGL14.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
   ```