# How to mask OpenGL quad with another quad

Tags: opengl, mask

I am trying to make display a quad, but only when it is over an other quad that I know the position of. I thought about using that quad as a mask for the other quad, but I am unsure about how to do it (I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5097145/10718749) post that talks about masking, however in my case I don't have a mask texture; I only know the X, Y, width and height of the area to mask). The current solution I found is to use `glBlendFunc`, and it only works if I don't render anything behind it, which won't be the case later on.

```java
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
// draw the background quad, that is acting as the mask...
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE, GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO);
// draw the background quad again, this time it will act as a mask...
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
// draw the quads that will be masked...
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); // this is the blend func used for the rest of the rendering
```

Before drawing each frame, I also have a function that clears the screen:

```java
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
```

How could I make it so that whatever it is that I draw before that, it will only mask on the previous quad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict the rendering to a rectangular area than you can use the [Scissor Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Scissor_Test).
The scissor test has to be enabled ([`GL_SCISSOR_TEST`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnable.xhtml)) a nd th rectangular area can be set by [`glScissor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glScissor.xhtml). e.g.:

```
glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(x, w, width, height);
```